# how to change the formatting in the php code that renders questions from a text file

Tags: php, html, css, display

A webpage that displays quizzes generated from question.txt files is shown as follows:

[image]

**I have the following code that is in a php document.** As you can see, it is this part of the php that appears to generate the general appearance of the display, such as the title: "Test your Knowledge".

```
<!-- Main
============================================= -->
<section id="code">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align:center;">

        <p></br></br></br></br></p>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 text-left">
            <p></br></br></br></br></p>

            <?php include 'quiz-sidebar.php'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 text-center">

        <h2 class="section-heading" style="color:black;">Test Your Knowledge : <?php include "content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/title.txt"; ?></h2>
        <p></br></p>

        <div style="border-style: solid; border-radius: 5px; border-width: 5px;">
            <p></p>
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo "quiz-result.php?quiz=".$_GET['quiz']; ?>">

            <?php

                $loadedQuestions = readQuestions("content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/questions.txt");

                displayTheQuestions($loadedQuestions);

            ?>

            <input type="submit" name="submitquiz" value="Submit Quiz"/>



            </form>
            <p></p>
        </div>

            <p></br></br></br></br></p>
        </div></div>

    </div>
</section>
```

The HTML inside it is centre aligned, and I would like it to be left aligned. I would also like to allow for the ability for some introductory text to be added before question 1, without it automatically rendering as a question (with the answer bullets displaying).

**The format is:**
**Question.txt** file contains the questions

```
1. What is Python?: A) An ancient greek monster, B) A high level programming language, C) A low level programming language, D) A language only used for the web
2. Fill in the blanks. I _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ matters in python! : A) Indentation, B) Illustriousness, C)Inventiveness, D) Irritation
```

**Answer.txt** file contains the answers

The php that generates the questions - which is also inside the same php document as the first bit of MAIN code - is below

```
function readQuestions($filename) {

    $displayQuestions = array();

    if (file_exists($filename) && is_readable($filename)) {

        $questions = file($filename);

        foreach ($questions as $key => $value) {

            $displayQuestions[] = explode(":",$value);

        }               

    }

    else { echo "Error finding or reading questions file."; }

    return $displayQuestions;
}

function displayTheQuestions($questions) {

    if (count($questions) > 0) {

        foreach ($questions as $key => $value) {

            preg_match("/{{(\w*\d*\W*\D*)*}}/", $value[0], $output_array);



                $to_import = "content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] . "/". substr($output_array[0], 2, -2);             

            if (!empty($output_array)){
                $val = str_replace($output_array[0], "", $value[0]);

                echo "<b>$val</b><br/>";
                include ($to_import);

                echo "</br></br>";
            } else {
                echo "<b>$value[0]</b><br/>";
            }

            $choices = explode(",",$value[1]);

            foreach($choices as $value) {

                $letter = substr(trim($value),0,1);
                preg_match("/{{(\w*\d*\W*\D*)*}}/", $value, $output_array);
                $val = str_replace($output_array[0], "", $value);


                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$letter\" style=\"text-align:left;\">$val<br/>";


                if (!empty($output_array)){
                    $to_import = "content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] . "/". substr($output_array[0], 2, -2);  
                    echo "</br>";
                    include ($to_import);
                    echo "</br></br>";
                }

            }
      echo "<br/>";

        }

    }

    else { echo "No questions to display."; }

}
```

The main question is how to go about **formatting the text** inside the question.txt file (rendered by the php code above) which is displayed on the page, as explained above. (left align, as well as adding additional information without it being a question)

Comment: interesting question - where do you want the additional "text" to go? Does it have to be inside the border, or can it be outside?

Comment: Open to ideas. Ideally, inside the border.

Comment: Why do you have `style="text-align:center;"` in the top level *div*? This is what's making the entire content centered. Moreover, this question not related to PHP, it's related to *css*.

Comment: Hi Rajdeep, what would I have to change it to, to change the alignment of the questions displayed. That's all the formatting I need to achieve (for the first part of the question anyway).

Comment: I've tried changing it to: text-align:left, but that didn't work .....

Comment: For the second part of the question, you need to "call" another file just below <h2 class="section-heading" style="color:black;">Test Your Knowledge : <?php include "content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/title.txt"; ?></h2> you could render another box on top of the existing questions box, which could have your introductory text.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your question could be achieved by creating a link (above where the questions are rendered) to another text or php file, like so:

```
 <div style="border-style: solid; border-radius: 5px; border-width: 1px;">
                <p></p>
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo "quiz-result.php?quiz=".$_GET['quiz']; ?>">

                <?php

                    $loadedQuestions = readQuestions("content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/additionalinfo.php");

                    displayTheQuestions($loadedQuestions);

                ?>
```

Note the additionalinfo.php which is being loaded instead of what you have originally. Php won't let you deal with html files, so it would have to be a php or txt file you load here.

Comment: This does load another file, but still does so while loading it in question form (so produces a bullet point (for answer entry) after each line of text...